# On Linux-64 (x86_64) integer value 16 gets truncated to 0

Tags: c, x86-64

I'm facing a weird problem on some (*not all*) 64-bit linux,
where **int value 16** gets truncated to **zero**.

- is truncation is because casting int to void* and again back to int (understand that this is not a good practice)

  - 16 becomes hex-10 and http://qb64.net/wiki/index.php?title=%26B
  - though void* is 8 byte on 64-bit OS, it can estimate only LSBs?? is this the cause??
    If so why this is not easily reproducible all the time??
  - or this is due to big-endian??
  - Sample source code as below

SAMPLE SOURCE

```
    int main() {
    int i = 0;
    void *ptr = NULL;
    printf("\nsizeof - void(*) : %d , int : %d", sizeof(void*), sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          ptr = &i;
          printf("\n%d", *((int*)ptr));
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Endianess would only matter when you send a variable over say network or you try to read individual bytes. When you read a variable as a type, it would be read correctly whether big or little endian

Comment: Does this truncation occur with your sample program? If so, what is its exact output?

Comment: I have tried this code on Linux 64 gcc and it always gives the right output prints 0 - 19 in loop, sizeof poiter is 8 and that of int is 4. I have not seen 16 truncated to 0. I have never heard of this "only estimate the LSB" and doubt any such thing exists

Comment: Your printfs for sizeof should be `%zu` not `%d`, especially since size_t is 8 bytes on x86-64.

Comment: I read only estimate the LSB here - http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0005/

Comment: not reproducible with sample program I have provided :(

Comment: "*... casting int to void** *and again back to int  ...*" at least your sample does not do this. The article you linked in your comment does not talk about this either. It referrs to converting pointer values to (32bit) `int`s and back. This also isn't done by your sample code.

Comment: casting int to void* ---> ptr = &i;
 getting it back --->      printf("\n%d", *((int*)ptr));

Comment: You're probably munging the value somewhere -- overwriting your 16 with a 0 -- so when you print it you get a 0 instead.  Almost certainly has nothing to do with anything you've posted here.

Comment: `ptr=&i` is not casting, at least not `int` to `void*`, its taking the address of `i`. You do not do `printf("\n%d", ((int)ptr));` in the OP. @Puneri

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate the issue described in the document referenced in the OP's comments mod your code like this:

```
      ptr = &i;
      printf("\n%d", (int)ptr))
```

To see that the address changed add this line:

```
      printf("\n%p", &i))
```

And see the two values printed are different.

All this assumes `sizeof(void*)` to be greater as `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: yes, will try this..Thanks, it should have clicked me to check address. Thanks again, will update if this helps to identify the root cause.

Comment: No, **do not update the OP**. No-one will ever be able to follow nad understand the thread of comments on the OP then. @Puneri

Comment: The address will not change. For a given run of the function i will be stored at a fixed address that is relative to the stack pointer since it is an auto variable.

Comment: Not the address itself changes, but what is printed out. The first call to ´printf()´ omites the most significant 4byte of the address, as it is printed by the second call to ´printf()´. @RobinCaron